# List URL Route Flask

Tags: python, list, flask

I have a list

`imageIds = ["zw8SeIUW", "f28BYZ"]`

which is constantly being added added to. I want to be able to access my site at `/images/zw8SeIUW` and all the other `imageIds`.

Why wouldn't something like this work? How do I get it to work?

```
for anImage in imageIds:
    @app.route('/images/<anImage>')
    def imagePage():
        return render_template('imagePage.html')
```

Answer (score 4):

`imagePage` function will be overwritten and only the last one will remain. (because `def blah(..)` overwrites old one).

Instead of defining multiple functions, how about coding the view as follow?

```
@app.route('/images/<image>')
def imagePage(image):
    if image not in imageIds:
        abort(404)
    else:
        return render_template('imagePage.html')
```